# Calling a method

Tags: objective-c

How can I call a method that is written in textfield when a button is pressed.

Comment: the question is very unclear. please explain in plain english.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to include a compiler or interpreter for whatever language you're writing in the textfield, call that on the input, passing it whatever data from the rest of your program is relevant, and then run the output of the compilation process. Overall, it's a non-trivial task.